# How to blend an imported image with my custom Incscape file?

Tags: inkscape, svg, import

Is there anyway to import an image to Incscape. Suppose I have downloaded an Image from internet. Then Imported it to Incscape like this---

[image]

Now I want to change its texture like `fill & stroke` and blend with my custom svg. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What image format is your imported image? SVG too, or a bitmap?

Comment: @userunknown It's a bitmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inkscape can change the fill and stroke of a **[vector graphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics)**.

If you want, you can [trace](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Trace.html) the imported bitmap and change fill and stroke of the resulting vector.